# Matplotlib/Tkinter - customizing toolbar tooltips

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created an application based on Tkinter that uses Matplotlib for plotting a waveform. I wonder how I could change the tooltips for the Matplotlib toolbar buttons (I need to translate the English descriptions since my application is in Czech language). I'd also like to change/translate or just remove the descriptions (`pan/zoom`, `zoom rect`) that appear next to the toolbar panel when clicking on the zoom or pan button.

I found some useful tips concerning how to add or remove buttons from the toolbar, but haven't found any advice for customizing the tooltips/descriptions. I think it would be similar to the former case in that I'd need to create a new toolbar class based on `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg` and modify it in some way. Any advices on how this could be done? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**PART 1**

So this should be pretty straight forward. The `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg` class inherits from `NavigationToolbar2` which can be found in `matplotlib.backend_bases`. If you look at `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg`, you will see that the pop-up text for the buttons is stored in an attribute called `self.toolitems`. This attribute is inherited from the base class, where it is defined as:

```
# list of toolitems to add to the toolbar, format is:                                                                             
# (                                                                                                                               
#   text, # the text of the button (often not visible to users)                                                                   
#   tooltip_text, # the tooltip shown on hover (where possible)                                                                   
#   image_file, # name of the image for the button (without the extension)                                                        
#   name_of_method, # name of the method in NavigationToolbar2 to call                                                            
# )                                                                                                                               
toolitems = (
    ('Home', 'Reset original view', 'home', 'home'),
    ('Back', 'Back to  previous view', 'back', 'back'),
    ('Forward', 'Forward to next view', 'forward', 'forward'),
    (None, None, None, None),
    ('Pan', 'Pan axes with left mouse, zoom with right', 'move', 'pan'),
    ('Zoom', 'Zoom to rectangle', 'zoom_to_rect', 'zoom'),
    (None, None, None, None),
    ('Subplots', 'Configure subplots', 'subplots', 'configure_subplots'),
    ('Save', 'Save the figure', 'filesave', 'save_figure'),
    )
```

The second item in each tuple is the text that is pops up when you mouse-over the button. To override this, just subclass and make your own version of `toolitems`.

For example (with filler text):

```
import numpy as np
import Tkinter as tk
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

# custom toolbar with lorem ipsum text
class CustomToolbar(NavigationToolbar2TkAgg):
    def __init__(self,canvas_,parent_):
        self.toolitems = (
            ('Home', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'home', 'home'),
            ('Back', 'consectetuer adipiscing elit', 'back', 'back'),
            ('Forward', 'sed diam nonummy nibh euismod', 'forward', 'forward'),
            (None, None, None, None),
            ('Pan', 'tincidunt ut laoreet', 'move', 'pan'),
            ('Zoom', 'dolore magna aliquam', 'zoom_to_rect', 'zoom'),
            (None, None, None, None),
            ('Subplots', 'putamus parum claram', 'subplots', 'configure_subplots'),
            ('Save', 'sollemnes in futurum', 'filesave', 'save_figure'),
            )
        NavigationToolbar2TkAgg.__init__(self,canvas_,parent_)


class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self._init_app()

    # here we embed the a figure in the Tk GUI
    def _init_app(self):
        self.figure = mpl.figure.Figure()
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure,self.root)
        self.toolbar = CustomToolbar(self.canvas,self.root)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.plot_widget = self.canvas.get_tk_widget()
        self.plot_widget.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas.show()

    # plot something random
    def plot(self):
        self.ax.imshow(np.random.normal(0.,1.,size=[100,100]),cmap="hot",aspect="auto")
        self.figure.canvas.draw()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MyApp(root)
    app.plot()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This should give you a normal embedded matplotlib figure, but when you mouse-over the buttons you will get something like:

[image: Custom toolbar text example]

**PART 2**

The second part of the question is less elegant. The text for "pan/zoom" and "zoom rect" is hardcoded into the `pan` and `zoom` methods of the toolbar. The actual text is held in the `self.mode` attribute of the toolbar. The easiest way to overwrite what this produces is to make subclass wrappers for the baseclass `pan` and `zoom` methods.

These wrappers go in the `CustomToolbar` class from above like:

```
def pan(self):
    NavigationToolbar2TkAgg.pan(self)
    self.mode = "I'm panning!" #<--- whatever you want to replace "pan/zoom" goes here
    self.set_message(self.mode)

def zoom(self):
    NavigationToolbar2TkAgg.zoom(self)
    self.mode = "I'm zooming!" #<--- whatever you want to replace "zoom rect" goes here
    self.set_message(self.mode)
```

This is just one way to do this, another might be to wrap the `set_message` method to catch and translate specific bits of text.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works just the way I wanted it to work :-).

Comment: What does `toolbar.update()` do exactly? I used this example to modify the default behavior of the navigation toolbar, which works nicely except `update()` doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: It updates the internal state of the NavigationToolbar2TkAgg object and I think it also waits for queued requests to be completed.