# Remove option from NavigationToolbar2TkAgg?

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, navigationbar, subplot

I'm learning how to use matplotlib, and now I have a problem. When I create a Figure in "tkinter project" and give it a subplot, I use NavigationToolbar2TkAgg to create a toolbar. In the current toolbar that appears , i want to remove the configure subplot option but couldn't find a way to do so.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this is in principle already given in this question: [How to modify the navigation toolbar easily in a matplotlib figure window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695678/how-to-modify-the-navigation-toolbar-easily-in-a-matplotlib-figure-window)

But it may not be obvious how to use it. So we may adapt the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23179396/4124317) with a CustomToolbar. The Toolbars `toolitems` attribute can be changed as to remove the unwanted `"Subplots"` button.

```
import numpy as np
import Tkinter as tk
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

# custom toolbar with lorem ipsum text
class CustomToolbar(NavigationToolbar2TkAgg):
    toolitems = filter(lambda x: x[0] != "Subplots", NavigationToolbar2TkAgg.toolitems)


class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self._init_app()

    # here we embed the a figure in the Tk GUI
    def _init_app(self):
        self.figure = mpl.figure.Figure()
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure,self.root)
        self.toolbar = CustomToolbar(self.canvas,self.root)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.plot_widget = self.canvas.get_tk_widget()
        self.plot_widget.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas.show()

    # plot something random
    def plot(self):
        self.ax.plot([1,3,2])
        self.figure.canvas.draw()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MyApp(root)
    app.plot()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

*Note: In newer versions of matplotlib you should use `NavigationToolbar2Tk` instead of `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg`*

Comment: Looks like in more recent versions of `matplotlib`, the toolbar has been renamed to `NavigationToolbar2Tk`.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Indeed, that's why I mentionned it in the last sentence.