# How to add an "edit" option to Tkinter Matplotlib navigation toolbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, toolbar

When using matplotlib [normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMJ1U.png) the navigation toolbar has 8 options including an "Edit axis, curves and image parameters" options highlighted here in blue.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   
y = [i**2 for i in range(101)]
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

But when plotted in [tkinter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7ZPU.png) GUI, there are only 7 options - the edit option is the one needed and is missing. Also, the subplot options dialogue looks completely different.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
fig = plt.Figure(figsize = (5, 5),dpi = 100)
y = [i**2 for i in range(101)]
plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plot1.plot(y)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master = root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas,root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

From this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172916/matplotlib-tkinter-customizing-toolbar-tooltips) it seems like this is something to do with default options being overwritten by the tkinter library, specifically the *NavigationToolbar2Tk* class. Can someone help with adding the edit option back into the tkinter toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Matplotlib` can use different `backends` to display plot window.

Normally it uses `PyQt` but you can run it with `Tk`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.switch_backend('tkagg')

y = [i**2 for i in range(101)]
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

`PyQt` uses [NavigationToolbar2QT](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/3e32cc7e88d6d583942335dff4c83b4b7dd13ae9/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt.py#L622) which adds button to run function [edit_properties](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/3e32cc7e88d6d583942335dff4c83b4b7dd13ae9/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt.py#L689)
but `Tk` uses [NavigationToolbar2Tk](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/3e32cc7e88d6d583942335dff4c83b4b7dd13ae9/lib/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py#L510) which doesn't have this function.

They also use different code to create window with subplot options.

The same problem is when you create `Tkinter` program.It has to use `NavigationToolbar2Tk` which doesn't have `edit_properties`.

You will have to create own `NavgationToolbar` and add own function to edit properites.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as msg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyToolbar(NavigationToolbar2Tk):
    
    def __init__(self, canvas, parent):
        
        self.toolitems = (
            ('Home', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'home', 'home'),
            ('Back', 'consectetuer adipiscing elit', 'back', 'back'),
            ('Forward', 'sed diam nonummy nibh euismod', 'forward', 'forward'),
            (None, None, None, None),
            ('Pan', 'tincidunt ut laoreet', 'move', 'pan'),
            ('Zoom', 'dolore magna aliquam', 'zoom_to_rect', 'zoom'),

            # new button in toolbar
            ("Customize", "Edit axis, curve and image parameters", "subplots", "edit_parameters"),                    

            (None, None, None, None),
            ('Subplots', 'putamus parum claram', 'subplots', 'configure_subplots'),
            ('Save', 'sollemnes in futurum', 'filesave', 'save_figure'),
            
        )
        super().__init__(canvas, parent)

    def edit_parameters(self):
        print("You have to create edit_parameters()")
        msg.showwarning("Warning", "You have to create edit_parameters()")
        
# --- main ---

y = [i**2 for i in range(101)]

root = tk.Tk()

fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plot1.plot(y)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)
#canvas.draw()

#toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar = MyToolbar(canvas, root)  # <-- uses own Toolbar
#toolbar.update()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks furas for taking the time to reply. It is a shame that such a useful option is not already included. It is beyond my current ability to recreate the "figure options" popup so I will leave the chart static.